# Why are we using getchar() in while loop to receive values and getch or getche function cannot be used?

Tags: c

Why are we using **getchar()** function in **while loop** to receive values in **write mode**, why can getch or getche functions not be used?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    clrscr();
    FILE *f;
    char r;
    f=fopen("muster_up.txt","w");
    while((r=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        fputc(r,f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    f=fopen("muster_up.txt","r");
    while((r=fgetc(f))!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%c",r);
    }
    fclose(f);
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getchar is a standard c function, in stdio.h,
getch, getche are non standard functions, used in old Windows/MS-DOS systems, they are in conio.h

getch and getche both do not wait for the user to hit enter, just read in the character immediately. getch does not echo the character as well, but getche does.

This is how it works: getchar is called, the stdio input buffer is empty, so it waits for user input. The user types a string of characters (a sentence), presses enter, those characters get stored in the input buffer, then getchar gets the first character from that. Since we have called it in a loop, it will read all the characters from the input buffer until it is empty, then wait.

Try using getch: the program will exit out if you don’t type a character immediately. Also getchar offers more flexibility to the user to type.

getchar, and the above functions get the input from the keyboard.